# Combine array and add key for each array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I just can't find the right question for this

pretty much merging array From this

```
$arr1 = ["temp1", "temp2", "temp3"];
$arr2 = [5, 7, 2];
```

to this

```
$combined = [["name" => "temp1", "number" => 5], ["name" => "temp2", "number" => 7], ["name" => "temp3", "number" => 2]];
```

any idea to do it in most efficient way other than foreach?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this question? What difficulties did you encounter in the process?

Comment: I can't find the command to do it efficiently

Comment: Of course i could do it with foreach, i just wonder if there is a specific function geared toward this question.

Comment: You know using `foreach` sometimes might be more efficient for array than some in-built functions. Arguably those functions are more readable than using foreach. They have negligible performance difference. Moreover you could create a function that takes these two arrays and return the combined result for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in function [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) actually can work with multiple arrays:

```
$result = array_map(function($value1, $value2) {
    return ["name" => $value1, "number" => $value2];
}, $arr1, $arr2);
```

[Here are](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/501f4ab2923b657b6bd5356ca72f0d635b636c37) some benchmarks comparing with simple foreach

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer i'm looking for. I kind of missed that array_map can receive 2 argument when i read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr1 = ["temp1", "temp2", "temp3"];
$arr2 = [5, 7, 2];
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value)
{
  $r[$key]['name'] = $value;
        $r[$key]['number'] = $arr2[$key];
    }
  print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a foreach loop,

```
$result = [];
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
    $resutl[] = array("name"=>$value,"number"=>$arr2[$key]);
}
```

Comment: *any idea to do it in most efficient way other than foreach?*

Comment: I'm just stating what is in the question, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following code to get your result

```
$arr1 = ["temp1", "temp2", "temp3"];
$arr2 = [5, 7, 2];
$count = count($arr1);
$combined = array();
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $combined[$i]['name'] = $arr1[$i];
    $combined[$i]['number'] = $arr2[$i];
}
```